# android activity comes to foreground after alarm manager

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, foreground

I have application, which makes event in alarm manager, and at specific time its called.
Code looks like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,req_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);    
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7,
                    pendingIntent);
```

Intent calls this activity.

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        //Change ringer mode
        //Add notification in status bar
        //Other booring stuff here...
        Toast.makeText(this,"Finishing",2000).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

in booring stuffthere are is code which should run in background (change ringermode)

Everything works for me, except one thing. Whenever the alarm manager calls my activity - the application comes to foreground. 
When it only should change ringer mode in background, and add notification in status bar.

Any way to not allow application come to foreground?

Comment: You should use a service instead: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do all of this in a [BroadCastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). There is no UI, and there is a `Context` variable passed on to the Receiver's `onReceive()` method which allows you to basically do anything the Activity does, without having an actual UI. This means that you can set the ringer, show the status bar notification, etc. 
Your BroadcastReceiver class should look something like:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Change ringer mode
    //Add notification in status bar
    //Other boring stuff here...
    Toast.makeText(context,"Finishing",2000).show();
    }
}
```

Note that for your `Toast`, the variable named `context` is used.

And your `AlarmManager` code should look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,req_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);    
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7,
                    pendingIntent);
```

Your manifest should have this:

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver" >
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I tryed broadcast reciever at start... For some reason - it didnt work for me! (alarm manager didnt call it). Tryed different tuts, something didnt work for me all time.

Comment: Don't forget you only have about 10 seconds to do work in a broadcast receiver, after that there is not guarantee it will keep running.

Comment: Unless you're looping a lot, their code seems to be in the time frame for 10 seconds.

Comment: Ok tnx, Im gonna try this again. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

and you have an Activity with nothing to display. Since you are already calling `finish();` in your code, it will look like it is running in background.

Comment: <activity android:name=".AlarmActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
                  />
After this - my application still opens...
I added alarm, changed to chrome, and when alarm went off - changed back to my app :(

Comment: Just call finish(); in your app after your calculations or job done.

Comment: I already have finish();
Without finish(); it hangs in "blank" screen.

Comment: When you have finish(), it means that your activity no longer exists, How can it be possible. Maybe finish is not called at all.

Comment: maybe it opens different (default) activity window after calling finish() ?

Comment: In that case just call your last activity with these flags: CLEAR_TOP and CLEAR_TASK and maybe SINGLE_TASK