# Is it possible to display the UI of a main activity in an Android app only upon clicking of the start icon?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, alarmmanager

I have an Alarmmanager that is repeatedly calling an AlarmReceiver. The AlarmReceiver in turn calls an activity (com.example.testapp.Activity). My problem is that after few calls the UI of my main activity is displayed again, which should not be the case. What can be done to prevent the UI from popping up?

I already tried to set (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION) in the AlarmReceiver. My main activity has android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay in the manifest.

I only want the UI of the main activity to be displayed when the user clicks the icon for starting the app. (Then the user clicks the start button of the main activity and from there on everything should run without UI).

Here is the AlarmReceiver code:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //start activity
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.example.testapp", "com.example.testapp.Activity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Here is the activity code:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class Activity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // a lot of code
```

Here is the main activity:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

   findViewById(R.id.startAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm begin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // instantiate AlarmService.java
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
            // start service
            startService(intent);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;
            /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Here is the code of the AlarmManager:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

             {

                PendingIntent pendingIntent;

                /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmService.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                int interval = 10000;

                manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Thanks. My problem was actually solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996366/android-activity-comes-to-foreground-after-alarm-manager